# Get names of all keys in the collection using Go

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, go, slice, mgo

I'd like to get the names of all the keys in a MongoDB collection.

For example, from this:

```
 "Id": ObjectId("5f5a010d431c4519dcda0e3d")
            "title": "App"
            "query": ""
            "db": ""
            "widgettype": ""
            "tablename": "active_instance"
            fields:Object
                user:"name",
                key:"passcode"
            "status": "active"
            "inlibrary": ""
            "createdts": 1599733804
```

**Using "gopkg.in/mgo.v2" and "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson" packages**.

```
err := mongodbSession.DB(dbName).C(collectionName).Find(bson.M{}).One(&result)
var keyset []string
    for index, _ := range result {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", index)
        keyset = append(keyset, index)
    }

    fmt.Println(keyset)
```

getting output as this

```
[_id title query db widgettype  status fields inlibrary createdts ]
```

**child key is not being featched that is user and key**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded documents will appear as another `bson.M` values inside your `result`, so you have to use a recursion to also traverse those.

Here's how you can do that:

```
func getKeys(m bson.M) (keys []string) {
    for k, v := range m {
        keys = append(keys, k)
        if m2, ok := v.(bson.M); ok {
            keys = append(keys, getKeys(m2)...)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Example using it:

```
m := bson.M{"Id": bson.ObjectId("5f5a010d431c4519dcda0e3d"),
    "title":      "App",
    "query":      "",
    "db":         "",
    "widgettype": "",
    "tablename":  "active_instance",
    "fields": bson.M{
        "user": "name",
        "key":  "passcode",
    },
    "status":    "active",
    "inlibrary": "",
    "createdts": 1599733804,
}

keys := getKeys(m)
fmt.Println(keys)
```

Which will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CxPQMic8rUm)):

```
[db widgettype createdts inlibrary _id title query tablename
  fields user key status]
```

If you look at the results, `user` and `key` are included, but it's not possible to tell if they were fields of the document or that of an embedded document.

You may choose to prefix fields of embedded documents with the field name of the embedded document field itself, e.g. to get `fields.user` and `fields.key`.

This is how you can do that:

```
func getKeys(m bson.M) (keys []string) {
    for k, v := range m {
        keys = append(keys, k)
        if m2, ok := v.(bson.M); ok {
            for _, k2 := range getKeys(m2) {
                keys = append(keys, k+"."+k2)
            }
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Which would output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pjfscsAHbX0)):

```
[createdts title query db status inlibrary _id widgettype tablename
    fields fields.user fields.key]
```

Also note that the above solutions do not handle arrays. If you have arrays, you should also iterate over them, and if they contain another array or object, you should do the same (recursively). It's an exercise for you to extend it to handle arrays too.

Answer (score 0):

Package "gopkg.in/mgo.v2" and "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson" are outdated. Replace by "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson" and "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo". Recursion must be used to retrieve nested fields.
Assume the database "store" has collection "users" with this document

```json
{"fields": {
  "user": "alex",
  "nickname": "ferguson",
}}
```

The code to retrieve keys from the collection is:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))

    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
    var docRaw bson.Raw
    res := client.Database("store").Collection("users").FindOne(context.Background(), bson.D{})

    err = res.Decode(&docRaw)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)

    }
    elements, err := docRaw.Elements()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    var keys []string
    for _, e := range elements {
        keys = append(keys, getKey(e)...)
    }
    fmt.Println(keys)
}

func getKey(e bson.RawElement) []string {
    if e.Value().Type != bson.TypeEmbeddedDocument {
        return []string{e.Key()}
    }
    var result []string
    nested, _ := e.Value().Document().Elements()
    for _, n := range nested {
        nKeys := getKey(n)
        for _, k := range nKeys {
            result = append(result, fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", e.Key(), k))
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Output:

```bash
[_id fields.user fields.nickname]
```